# Purchase Subscription using consumable in-app purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, subscription

I have set up my consumable in-apps on AppStoreConnect. Added auto-renewable subscriptions for every month. I want the user to be able to buy subscriptions using purchased consumable in-apps.

I couldn't find any way to do that. Is it possible?

Comment: No.  You can't purchase in app purchases with other in app purchases. Why would you want to do such a thing?  The subscription equivalent of consumable IAPs is non-renewing subscriptions.